# Retrieving data from Parse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I manage to have the user record information name, headline, age, and even gender selection as well as gender preference in parse. Now I want to be able to retrieve the information, with conditions. For instance, if the current user selected that he is looking for a female, than it would only display queryequal female.

Below is the code where the user enter the information that is submitted to parse:

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected ImageView mprofilePicture;
    RadioButton male, female;
    String gender;
    RadioButton lmale, lfemale;
    String lgender;

    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

        v.requestFocus();

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
        mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
        male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
        female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
        lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
        lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);

        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();



                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                    /*   // Locate the image from the ImageView
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                           fron image view);
                    // Convert it to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

                    // Create the ParseFile
                    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePicture.png", image);
                    // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                    file.saveInBackground();

                    // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
                    currentUser.put("ImageName", "AndroidBegin Logo");

                    // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
                    currentUser.put("ProfilePicture", file); 

                    // Create the class and the columns
                    currentUser.saveInBackground();  */
                    if(male.isChecked())
                        gender = "Male";
                    else
                        gender = "Female";

                    if(lmale.isChecked())
                        lgender = "Male";
                    else
                        lgender = "Female";


                    currentUser.put("Name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("Age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("Headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.put("Gender", gender);
                    currentUser.put("Looking_Gender", lgender);

                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });



        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });




        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Below is the code that I am brainstorming could be used to retrieved information:

```
currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
            names = new ArrayList<String>();
           // String userActivitySelectionName = "";


            ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
           query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
               query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName","");
               query.whereNotEqualTo("Looking_Gender",currentUserID);
```

The issue i have now is setting a condition, where if a guy wants to be match with guy so only those guys who want to be match with guys information returns, and vice-versa for women.
Let me know, if this is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think the query should be query.whereEqualTo("Gender","female"); //if looking for female and query.whereEqualTo("Gender","male"); //for male

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. So if your gender is male, it would automatically give you female? What if you are a male who wants a male, or a female who wants a female. I also have another column in parse where user record another information like Looking_Gender so if your Gender is male, and looking for a female than it would only show the female (Gender) who are looking for male (Looking_Gender), or if a male (Gender) looking for a male (Looking_Gender) than it would only return the male looking for a male, but for a guy looking for a guy i can't return everyone looking for a guy

Comment: well it does not mind whatever gender of your user is, just give a choice to your user if he/she require which gender and as per their requirements why don't you build a query like i suggested..

Comment: @user3827788 - please accept my answer below as correct if it helped you achieve what you needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line will ensure that the Users returned are only users who match the gender for which the current user is looking.  That is, if I'm looking for a female, the constraint below will ensure that only females are returned.

```
query.whereEqualTo("Gender", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender"));
```

The following line will ensure that the Users returned are only users who are looking for other users that match the gender for which I am.  That is, if I'm a male, the constraint below will ensure that only users who are looking for males will be returned.

```
query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender"));
```

If I understand your question correctly, using the above two constraints together should achieve what you're looking for.